# how to get new value through session

Tags: php, session

I want to get the value of php variable through session. Each time when i click on refresh image of captcha,php variable i.e $code contains new value. I used session to get that value. I m getting the value only once but when i click on refresh image the value in session is not changing. How can i get the value repeatedly using session here is my code:

code of captchaImages.php:

```
$captcha = new CaptchaCode();
$code = str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));
$captcha1 = new CaptchaImages();
$captcha1-> GenerateImage($width,$height,str_decrypt($code));
session_start();
$_SESSION['code_captcha'] = $code;
```

code of my index.php where i want to get new value of session:

```
function refresh_captcha()
    {

        jQuery.get('<?php echo CAPTCHA_PLUGIN_URL . "/captcha_images.php"?>', function(encoded_code) {
            <?php
            session_start();
            ?>
            jQuery('#security_check').val("<?php echo $_SESSION['code_captcha'];?>");
            jQuery('#captcha_img').attr("src","<?php echo CAPTCHA_PLUGIN_URL . "/captcha_images.php"?>");
        });
    }
```

Comment: You're mixing Server side code (PHP) with Client side code (JS). It may work somehow but it's highly unreadable

Comment: Last time I saw this question, the condition was no cookie/sessions... I think it slightly changes the conditions :D

Comment: how can i get $_SESSION['code_captcha'] = $code; value in refresh_captcha()?

Comment: You should have be getting it, once you have requsted by get() the relevant file. Your only problem is that the session is one and the same. Maybe destroying it, as it's pointed in the answers will help

Comment: not working, still getting value only once

Comment: Your problem is too localized. Last time you asked, and we provide you an ajax which get's the json, it was working correctly, and only on your machine was not. You have a core problem somewhere else, which you should investigate by yourself.

Comment: thanx 4 ur advice Royal Bg

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change the value of session directly. 
write

```
session_destroy(); or you can also write unset($_SESSION['code_captcha']);
```

above

```
session_start();
```

what this will do it will destroy the previous session value and it will accept the new value of captcha